# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipesCount' of undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic to build a hybrid app and just updated everything.

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.2.0

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.2.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.2.0
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:

Node       : v8.0.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13
```

I installed my android and ios platform then I ran 'ionic cordova resources' to install my new icon and splash. I'm trying to run 'ionic upload and I'm getting this error:

```
`Running app-scripts build: 

[15:06:57]  build dev started ... 
[15:06:57]  clean started ... 
[15:06:57]  clean finished in 2 ms 
[15:06:57]  copy started ... 
[15:06:57]  transpile started ... 
[15:07:00]  transpile finished in 2.82 s 
[15:07:00]  preprocess started ... 
[15:07:00]  deeplinks started ... 
[15:07:00]  deeplinks finished in 23 ms 
[15:07:00]  preprocess finished in 24 ms 
[15:07:00]  webpack started ... 
[15:07:00]  copy finished in 3.13 s 
[15:07:09]  webpack finished in 9.33 s 
[15:07:09]  sass started ... 
[15:07:11]  sass finished in 1.45 s 
[15:07:11]  postprocess started ... 
[15:07:11]  postprocess finished in 13 ms 
[15:07:11]  lint started ... 
[15:07:11]  build dev finished in 13.74 s 

_stream_readable.js:545
  switch (state.pipesCount) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipesCount' of undefined
    at module.exports.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:545:16)
    at module.exports.ZipArchiveOutputStream._smartStream (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/compress-commons/lib/archivers/zip/zip-archive-output-stream.js:184:11)
    at module.exports.ZipArchiveOutputStream._appendStream (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/compress-commons/lib/archivers/zip/zip-archive-output-stream.js:96:20)
    at module.exports.ArchiveOutputStream.entry (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/compress-commons/lib/archivers/archive-output-stream.js:88:10)
    at module.exports.ZipStream.entry (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/zip-stream/index.js:138:49)
    at Zip.append (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/archiver/lib/plugins/zip.js:53:15)
    at Archiver._moduleAppend (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/archiver/lib/core.js:172:16)
    at Archiver._onQueueTask (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/archiver/lib/core.js:370:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4045:9
    at process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2316:17)`
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**update: I ran 'ionic package build android' and got some new information

`(node:18146) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: channel closed
(node:18146) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: It is an [issue](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/issues/236) with Node.js 8 that should be [fixed](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/13374) in a future release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

install node@6 current lts from https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved in NodeJS v8.1.0