# Unexpected error while deploying firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am using firebase could functions for the first time. I am having trouble deploying the functions. It gives me the below error:

[image: error in my termimal]

Below is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
  "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
  "start": "npm run shell",
  "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
  "logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
 "engines": {
 "node": "8"
},
"dependencies": {
 "@google-cloud/logging": "^4.5.2",
 "firebase-admin": "^7.3.0",
 "firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",
 "stripe": "^6.34.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "eslint": "^5.12.0",
 "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
 "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
 },
"private": true
}
```

Below are the logs:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipesCount' of undefined
>       at module.exports.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:545:16)
>       at module.exports.ZipArchiveOutputStream._smartStream (/home/appinventiv-pc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/compress-commons/lib/archivers/zip/zip-archive-output-stream.js:184:11)
>       at module.exports.ZipArchiveOutputStream._appendBuffer (/home/appinventiv-pc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/compress-commons/lib/archivers/zip/zip-archive-output-stream.js:82:10)
>       at module.exports.ArchiveOutputStream.entry (/home/appinventiv-pc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/compress-commons/lib/archivers/archive-output-stream.js:86:10)
>       at module.exports.ZipStream.entry (/home/appinventiv-pc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/zip-stream/index.js:157:49)
>       at Zip.append (/home/appinventiv-pc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/archiver/lib/plugins/zip.js:54:15)
>       at Archiver._moduleAppend (/home/appinventiv-pc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/archiver/lib/core.js:179:16)
>       at Archiver._onQueueTask (/home/appinventiv-pc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/archiver/lib/core.js:400:8)
>       at /home/appinventiv-pc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4096:9
>       at Object.process (/home/appinventiv-pc/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2344:17)

If there is any other information i need to provide please let me know. I am new to firebase cloud functions and node.

Comment: Run the deploy command with `--debug` and edit the question to show the output that shows the specific error.

Comment: @DougStevenson added the logs. Please check

Comment: Please don't show screenshots of text.  Just copy the text into the question to make it easier to read and search.  Also please note the version of the Firebase CLI you're using (and make sure you're using the latest).

Comment: I updated the version of Firebase CLI but that din't help either

Comment: I'd contact Firebase support with a bug report.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Comment: @DougStevenson I did write an email to the firebase support but I didn't get any helpful response. I am really stuck in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very old version of node (8.0.0) that has a bug.  Upgrade your node version to something more recent.

(I found this information by doing a search with your error message.)

- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipesCount' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278093/typeerror-cannot-read-property-pipescount-of-undefined)
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/356
- https://github.com/archiverjs/node-zip-stream/issues/26
- https://github.com/archiverjs/node-compress-commons/issues/25